# Can Visual Studio be set up to remote debug a php based site housed on virtualbox?

Tags: php, visual-studio-2013, virtualbox, lamp, linux-mint

**My setup:**
One machine running Visual Studio 2013 pro and Oracle Virtualbox: Mint 17, Apache 2, PHP5, Mysql.
I've network mapped my home directory, using samba. The project is located off of my home directory, in a public_html folder. This set-up was requested because we develop in windows environment but the site is hosted on a ubuntu server.

**The Site:**
It is a PHP website using the codeigniter framework that, amongst other things, passes a generated page into PhantomJS to create a screen shot of the page to pass into a site generated pdf file as a report for the user.

**The problem:**
I can run the site as is on the Mint vbox both from /var/www and from {ip}/~userDir just fine. However some issues plague me that I would like to be able to use PHP tools for Visual Studio's (Devsense) ability to breakpoint the php itself and read the current state of objects. When I try to use VS (the iis express server that comes with VS I think) I can step into the code at my break point and easily view the state of my objects. However the only thing that refuses to work is the PhantomJS (though the VS IIS Only). Running the same process on the LAMP works just fine. (I.E)

```
$src = "var page = require('webpage').create(); page.viewportSize = { width: {$wi} , height: {$hi}};";
  if (isset($clipw) && isset($cliph)) {
      $src .= "page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: {$clipw}, height: {$cliph} };";
  }
$src .= "page.open('{$url}', function () {
         page.evaluate(function() {
               document.body.bgColor = 'white';
               });

         page.render('{$cache_job}');
               phantom.exit();
              });
         page.onError = function (msg, trace) {
             console.log(msg);
             trace.forEach(function(item) {
             console.log('  ', item.file, ':', item.line);
              })
         }";
$job_file = $jobs . $url_segs['host'] . crc32($src) . '.js';
file_put_contents($job_file, $src);
$exec = $bin_files . 'phantomjs ' . $job_file;
$escaped_command = escapeshellcmd($exec);
$output = exec($escaped_command, $outArray, $rtnVal );
$someError = error_get_last();
```

I 'assume' the roadblock is somewhere between the iis setup (which I'm not proficient in at all) and how i'm using a linux share from windows. The     `escapeshellcmd($exec)` command I'm using just before I pass into `exec()` renders the path differently in VS then it does on the LAMP server. I get no response (read as: stepping in and reading the states of each var after the line is executed) back at all from `$output = exec($escaped_command, $outArray, $rtnVal )` or even `$someError = error_get_last()`.

**The Question:**
Has anyone set up VS to use a virtual Linux server for testing php using breakponts? Can I set VS up so it uses the php engine from the LAMP instead of its own?

I know in the project options tab in the Servers area you can 'Use Custom Web Server', yet when I put the IP of the Virtualbox in that spot I get "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed." I know the server is there, the welcome page comes up when I put the same URL into the browser.

Thank you for taking the time to read this and any help you might have.

Comment: I didn't realize Visual Studio had any language support for PHP at all.  What a time to be alive!

Comment: I'm actually incredibly intrigued to know why you're using possibly one of the most over-complicated solutions I've ever seen instead of running with the Apache on your mint box with virtual networking as it looks like you're using, ditching IIS completely and using a native IDE instead of VS and IIS on the Mint install? (Edit: Missed a word)

Comment: @Brad Yep with the plugin you get IntelliSense, full php manual at the command (mouse over) and other goodies.

Comment: @Thom Did you know about PHPStorm? And Vagrant ... and puphpet.com

Comment: @ iamgory The thrust of the question is to not use the IIS, but use the Apache2 on the mint box. As for the rest I really enjoy VS and have never really had issues with it. Our team develops in Windows environments but our site is all Linux based. Its new to me.

Comment: @ Gregsparrow Yes PHPStorm looks good however we have to pay or own way for dev tools. I already have VS and 99% of the time i'm at 0 issue. If i can find my way round this issue i'd be golden again. Thanks though.

Comment: I have one step towards your goal. I'm able to breakpoint and debug running an Apache LAMP on my box with VS 2013 and Devsense PHP. So it's not the virtual box but I have broken free from IIS and the internal server. That requires XDEBUG and port 9000 to be open.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to debug an external virtual machine environment and this is how I do this using the [PHP Tools](https://www.devsense.com/) extension for Visual Studio and Xdebug.

Here are the steps as follows.

1. Make sure PHP Tools is installed in Visual Studio. Make sure Xdebug is installed and turned on within your virtual machine. I usually SSH in and in the `xdebug_on` command works.
2. Make sure the project your working on is a PHP project within Visual Studio
3. *Right Click* on your Project File and go to properties.[image]
4. Go to the server and enter your server url(whats your local domain url)
5. Set your xdebug port, defaulted its usually 9000 or 80.
6. Enter your File/Directory which is your path mapped on your local for example: C:/programfiles/www/wordpress-default/public_html
7. Enter your Absolute path on the Server for example: /srv/www/wordpress-default/public_html
8. Make sure you have administrative privileges to run Visual Studio.
9. Download and install the [Xdebug Helper extension for Chrome.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc?hl=en)
10. Create a break point run the debugger with F5.
11. Make sure Chrome Xdebug Helper is running.[image]

This is using the defaulted/'out of the box' settings for this machine so you may need to tweak these values. Hope this helps.